# how to undo git reset --merge ORIG_HEAD

Tags: git

I accidently did

```
$ git reset --merge ORIG_HEAD
```

and now my code has been reset. Does anyone know how to undo it?

how to undo

```
$ git reset --merge ORIG_HEAD
```

Comment: I don't understand the reference to the suggested duplicate. `git reset --merge` has nothing to do with merge resolution.